# Evaluate $\int_{0}^{2\pi}\sin^3(3e^{iz}+\frac{\pi}{4})\,dz$

Tags: complex-analysis, definite-integrals

If we assume $z$ is a complex number can you compute the following complex integral $\int_{0}^{2\pi}\sin^3(3e^{iz}+\frac{\pi}{4})\,dz$

I tried to change the variable putting $u=3e^{iz}+\frac{\pi}{4}$, but I couldn't proceed.

Comment: Are you supposed to know about sine and cosine integrals ?

Answer (score 2):

$du=i(u-\pi/4)dz$, so this is a contour integral around the circle of radius $3$, centre $\pi/4$.
$$\oint\frac{\sin^3u}{i(u-\pi/4)}du$$

Comment: possibly i am lack of some basic facts of complex analysis.  I know this integral cannot be zero because the circle goes around a singularity. But i dont know how i proceed

Comment: Check your notes to see how to deal with a singularity.

Comment: by local cauchy integral formula i see the result, is there any simple way to come up with the singularity